# Submodule still missing after import

Tags: python, import, dependencies, ipython

I have some sort of circular/mutual import causing problems in a complex project that I'm trying to track down in `ipython`.  My immediate issue is that I'm importing a submodule, but still getting an error, i.e.:

```
In [32]: import Figures
In [33]: import Figures.stuff
In [34]: Figures.stuff
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-903ae3688f13> in <module>()
----> 1 Figures.stuff

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stuff'
```

How is this possible?  Should I at least be getting some sort of import error in `[33]`?

This part of the file structure looks like:

```
Figures/
    __init__.py
    stuff.py
```

The `__init__.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'sans-serif': ['Times']})
# from . import stuff
```

If it matters, I'm using python2.7, usually with `from __future import absolute_import`.

---

***Edit***:  The problem goes away when I remove an import from a different module...  Why?!

```
Figures/
    ...
comparisons/
    __init__.py
    sets1.py
```

If I comment out `from . import sets1` inside `comparisons/__init__.py` the problem goes away.

In `sets1.py` I do:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
import Figures
import Figures.stuff
```

Comment: What does `__init__.py` say?

Comment: You might need to define `__all__` in `__init__.py`, check the [documentation about packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: @PeterWood even though I never use an `from ..... import *` statement?